# Converting a HSSFWorkbook into MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

My requirement is as follows. I have an Excel file generated. And it is of type `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook`.

I want to convert this into `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`.

```java
HSSFWorkbook workbook = myConverter.getWorkBook(myDTOList, timeZone.toString());
MultipartFile multiFile = (MultipartFile)workbook;
```

I am getting error with the above piece of code.

Comment: Please share the error.

Comment: Hi, It is not able to convert to MultiPartFile .

Comment: @aditya Are you want for download this file?